# D3 pie chart rendering in only one color

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, pie-chart

I am building a pie chart using the D3 library. Everything is going smoothly except for the colours. Data are stored in the normal Object format.

I defined colour variable as :

```
    var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
            .range(d3.schemeCategory10);
```

and my enter selection binding code is:

```
        var g = svg.selectAll("path")
              .data(pieArcs, keyField)
              .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.key); });

        var g2 = g
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .each(function(d) { this.dPrevious = d; })
            .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.key); })
            .attr('fill', d => color(d.data.key))
```

Changed every aspect, checked all D3 pie charts examples, reached the bottom of the internet, but only getting this (everything else is working):

[image: pie chart]

All I need is to have every arc distinguished in different color.

Comment: Can you try with `attr`? (i.e. `.attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.key); }`). If that doesn't work then `d.data.key` doesn't exists.

Comment: but this is written in my code patch under  `.attr('fill', d => color(d.data.key)) `. Still not working. But I am accessing the key of the data with this elsewhere in the code (not the colors for pie chart) and it is working

Comment: @adelriosantiago you were right, this `d.data.key` does not work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @adelriosantiago indicated `d.data.key` was not working. I have finally colored the piechart using `attr`

```
.attr("fill", d => color(keyFieldFunction(d.data)));
```

when the `keyFieldFunction` was defined back in the code as:

```
var GUPkeyField = function(d){return d.data.key};
```

[image: colored pie chart]